# Windows 7 Home Premium (OEM) activation issue on Acer laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, windows-activation

I have bought an Acer 5740 laptop that comes with Windows 7 Home Premium. When I install using eRecovery, it installs the Windows and is automatically activated, but it installs a lot of other software that I do not need. So I decided to download Windows 7 Home Premium image and install it using the CD key supplied with the laptop (on the back), but when I try to activate it it says "The Windows 7 Home Premium key you typed is invalid for activation" and it gives me an option to activate using the automated phone system.

I wanted to know why can't I activate it? Does this mean someone else might have activated it? Or is it because of the copy of Windows that comes in the hidden partition? I have also read in one forum that you have to buy a Windows CD from Acer. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Microsoft and tell them you reinstalled the W7 from DVD and used the Key from the COA sticker on the laptop, they will help you activate the software, don't mention where you got the DVD.

In the USA, call 1-888-725-1047

Comment: this means that it was because of the already activated windows that I got with the laptop?

Comment: Not sure, I have used COA keys before, some activate some don't, I always call the phone activation number when they don't.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are several versions of Windows - OEM (which is what you have), retail - buy at the store, open license - corporate...  You likely downloaded a different type of Windows rather than the OEM you needed.  Where did you download from?

Comment: My friend had MSDN subscription. I downloaded the windows from there and tried to use my key on the sticker